# Azure VM with Docker failing to connect

Tags: windows, azure, docker, virtual-machine, azure-xplat-cli

I'm trying to write a Powershell script to create a VM in Azure with Docker installed. From everything I've read, I should be able to do the following:

```
$image = "b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-14_04_3-LTS-amd64-server-20150908-en-us-30GB"

azure vm docker create -e 22 -l 'North Europe' --docker-cert-dir dockercert --vm-size Small <myvmname> $image $userName $password

docker --tls -H tcp://<myvmname>.cloudapp.net:4243 info
```

The vm creation works, however the docker command fails with the following error:

> An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://myvmname.cloudapp.net:4243/v1.20/info: dial tcp 40.127.169.184:4243: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Some articles I've found refer to port 2376 - but that doesn't work either.

Logging onto Azure portal and viewing the created VM - the Docker VM Extension doesn't seem to have been added and there's no endpoints other than the default SSH one. I was expecting these to have been created by the `azure vm docker create` command. Although I could be wrong with that bit.

A couple of example article I've looked at are here:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-docker-with-xplat-cli/
- http://blog.siliconvalve.com/2015/01/07/get-started-with-docker-on-azure/

However, there's plenty of other articles saying the same thing.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are doing nothing wrong. My azurecli-dockerhost connection had been working for months and failed recently. I re-created my docker host using "azure vm docker create" but it does not work any more.

I believe it is a bug that the azure-docker team has to fix.

For the time being, my solution is to:

1) Launch a Ubuntu VM WITHOUT using the Azure docker extension

2) SSH into the VM and install docker with these lines:

```
sudo su; apt-get -y update
apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
modprobe aufs
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

3) Run docker within this VM directly without relying on a "client" and in particular the azure cli.

If you insist on using the docker client approach, my alternative suggestion would be to update your azure-cli and try 'azure vm docker create' again. Let me know how it goes.

```
sudo su
apt-get update; apt-get -y install nodejs-legacy; apt-get -y install npm; npm install azure-cli --global
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try later today. Will also post an issue with the azure-docker team about it then.

Comment: Brilliant - this works :) I've gone with your first suggestion. I'm using plink in my PowerShell script to SSH into it and run a script file with your example. Then in that same linux script, I'm creating the docker containers. Then back in the Powershell script, I'm creating an endpoint for app I'm installing (Neo4j in this case). Works great :)

Comment: I've added another answer which a colleague found today. Just commenting here so you get notified about it, as it might help you too.

Answer (score 0):

To add an additional answer to my question, it turns out you can do the same using the `docker create` command ...

```
docker-machine create $vmname --driver azure --azure-publish-settings-file MySubscription.publishsettings
```

This method works for me.